# Why doesn't my pattern match?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a python script that will add some java code to a java source file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, getopt
import re

def read_write_file(infile):
        inf = open( infile, 'r' )
        pat = re.compile('setContentView\(R\.layout\.main\)\;')
        for line in inf:
                l=line.rstrip()
                if ( pat.match( l ) ):
                        print l
                        print """
            // start more ad stuff
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            // end more ad stuff

"""
                        sys.exit(0)
                else:
                        print l
        inf.close


def main(argv):
        inputfile = ''
        try:
                opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:",["ifile="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
                print 'make_main_xml.py -i <inputfile>'
                sys.exit(2)
        for opt, arg in opts:
                if opt == '-h':
                        print """
usage : make_main_activity.py -i <inputfile>

where <inputfile> is the main activity java file
like TwelveYearsaSlave_AdmobFree_AudiobookActivity.java
"""
                        sys.exit()
                elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
                        inputfile = arg
        read_write_file( inputfile )

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

... here is the typical input file this script will operate on ...

```
    public static Context getAppContext() {
            return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = getApplicationContext();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
```

... the actual java source file is huge but I just want to insert the text ...

```
            // start more ad stuff
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            // end more ad stuff
```

... right after ...

```
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

... but when I run my script the text I want to insert does not get inserted.
I assume there is something wrong with this line in my python script ...

```
        pat = re.compile('setContentView\(R\.layout\.main\)\;')
```

... I have tried many various other strings to compile.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `inf.close` should be `inf.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pat.match(l)` have to to match exactly with the string. It means that `l` must be `"setContentView(R.layout.main);"` in this case.

However , since you have spaces before `setContentView(...)`, you should use `pat.search(l)` instead, or change

```
pat = re.compile('setContentView\(R\.layout\.main\);')
```

to

```
pat = re.compile('^\s*setContentView\(R\.layout\.main\);\s*$')
```

for matching spaces.

Moreover, in this case you don't need regex. You can just check that line contains the  string by using `in` operator.

```
if "setContentView(R.layout.main);" in l:
```